# use stored procedure to select last item value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to select the last record value from my database by using stored procedure, to do this i set my `@UPID` parameter as `SCORE_IDENTITY()`, but there are no output result as all after i execute my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAuditLogSelect_NewUser]

@UPID   int
AS
BEGIN

SET @UPID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


SELECT
siUserProfile.UPID
,siUserProfile.ProfileType, siProfileType.RGDName AS ProfileTypeName
,siUserProfile.CBID, siCompany.ComName + ' - ' + siComBranch.ComBranchName AS CBName
,siUserProfile.FullName
,siUserProfile.ShortName
,siUserProfile.SerialCode
,siUserProfile.Serial
,siUserProfile.Gender



from siUserProfile WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join siUserProfileDetail WITH (NOLOCK) on siUserProfile.upid =             siUserProfileDetail.UPID 
left outer join siReferenceGroupDetail siProfileType WITH (NOLOCK) ON siUserProfile.ProfileType = siProfileType.RGDID
left outer join siComBranch WITH (NOLOCK) on siComBranch.CBID = siUserProfile.CBID
left outer join siCompany WITH (NOLOCK) ON siComBranch.CompanyID = siCompany.CompanyID


where siUserProfile.UPID = @UPID
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no output results"?
The proc returns an empty table or there is no return?
If case you cannt see an output, please press Display Estimation Plan button. The action can suggest you to create an index that most likely solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is meant to be used right after `insert`.  It won't work in a different session.

To retrieve the latest entry, try `top 1`:

```
select  top 1 *
...
where   siUserProfile.UPID = @UPID
order by
        siUserProfile.ID desc
```

Comment: the parameter @UPID for my query is a must, so do u have any idea for me to execute my stored procedure by given the last value?

Comment: Sure, just be sure to use `@UPID` as it was passed in.  Don't overwrite it with `scope_identity()`.

Answer (score 1):

You require to use IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’).

Please refer below link which illustrate difference between @@IDENTITY,SCOPE_IDENTITY() and IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’).

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have some primary key(PK) in your table. Write the procedure, in that procedure fire the query

```
     select * from Your_Table where PK_Column in(select max(PK_Column) from Your_Table)
```

This way you will be able to fetch the latest record from DB. By opening a cursor, you can play with record in your procedure.

Comment: brother i got another question now, i cannot perform select max as my query because if there are 200 concurrently user then i may not return the result i want !